# Handle Multiple Tab in Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, kotlin

I am making an Android browser app, I want to handle link click that has target='_blank', which will open in a new tab in normal browsers.

There is a method call `onCreateWindow` in `WebChromeClient` which is triggering when a `_blank` link clicked. But my question is how can I get the link URL? following code is just returning the current URL

```
override fun onCreateWindow(view: WebView?, isDialog: Boolean, isUserGesture: Boolean, resultMsg: Message?): Boolean {
    Toast.makeText(context, view?.url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    return super.onCreateWindow(view, isDialog, isUserGesture, resultMsg)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a way to capture the link URL.

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
override fun onCreateWindow(view: WebView?, isDialog: Boolean, isUserGesture: Boolean, resultMsg: Message?): Boolean {
    val newWebView = WebView(context)
    addView(context, newWebView)
    val transport = resultMsg?.obj as WebView.WebViewTransport
    transport.webView = newWebView

    val settings = newWebView.getSettings()
    settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
    settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true)
    settings.useWideViewPort = false
    newWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
        }

        override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
            Toast.makeText(context, url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
        }
    }
    resultMsg.sendToTarget()

    return true
}
```

By creating a new web and adding it to the `WebViewTransport`, you can add a new `WebViewClient` to that new `WebView` then its easy to capture that URL from `onPageStarted` method.

Comment: is addView a funciton which you defined somewhere else?

Comment: yes, it will add a new fragment with the webview.